# How write a new line in file using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, newline, cordova-plugin-file

I can write a file and append your content, but I can't create new lines.

Example: I need put one number per line

```
31/08/2016 00:01,0
31/08/2016 00:02,4
31/08/2016 00:03,0
31/08/2016 00:04,8
31/08/2016 00:05,0
31/08/2016 00:06,0
```

I try use `\n` and `\r` (before and after of line) to return but not work, all content are write in one line.

I'm using plugin cordova-plugin-file to write files, exactly this function [writeFile](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#append-a-file-using-alternative-methods-)

Them, how do new line?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I used:

`writer.write('Some message\n');`